# Perl remove matching pattern and store the rest to variable

Tags: perl

I would like to remove the matching pattern starting from end of the line and store the rest of the line to a variable how do it in perl ?

For Eg :

```
$ROOT = "/home/usr/bin";
```

I want to remove "/bin" from above $ROOT variable and print/store the rest. Will the below code work ?

```
$ROOT =s/^(.*?)(?=\/bin)/$1/g
print $ROOT;
```

Will the above code print below output,

```
/home/usr
```

Please note I may be wrong with above suggestion as I am new. Please help me out.

Comment: will it always be a directory or any string?

Comment: instead of asking "will it do this/that?", why not try it yourself?  you do have access to a perl interpreter, don't you?

Comment: That's a convoluted way of doing `$ROOT =~ s/\/bin$//`

Answer (score 7):

Or you could use [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my $ROOT = "/home/usr/bin";
print dirname($ROOT);
```

Output:

```
/home/usr
```

Comment: +1 This is the right way to do it when dealing with file names and path names.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
my $ROOT = "/home/usr/bin";
$ROOT =~ s!/bin$!!; # the delimiter is "!" to avoid escaping "/"
print $ROOT;
```

And like foampile said, you can test your regex with a `perl` interpreter. I recommend you the interactive `perl` shell [`perlconsole`](https://metacpan.org/release/SUKRIA/perlconsole-0.4/view/perlconsole) or [`Devel::REPL`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::REPL)

`perlconsole` :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've broken it by using a look-ahead. If you had written just

```
$ROOT =~ s/^(.*)\/bin/$1/
```

then it would work. To remove the last segment of any path, write

```
$ROOT =~ s|/[^/]*$||
```